# Can Refer a M-M table inside another table in asp .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have `Student`, `Teacher`, `Subject` tables.

`Teacher` and `Subject` have a M-M relationship

```
public class TeacherSubject
{
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }

    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public Subject Subject { get; set; }
}


builder.Entity<TeacherSubject>()
       .HasKey(i => new
           {
               i.SubjectId,
               i.TeacherId
           });

builder.Entity<TeacherSubject>()
       .HasOne(i => i.Subject)
       .WithMany(i => i.TeacherSubjects)
       .HasForeignKey(i => i.SubjectId);

builder.Entity<TeacherSubject>()
       .HasOne(i => i.Teacher)
       .WithMany(i => i.TeacherSubjects)
       .HasForeignKey(i => i.TeacherId);
```

Student can choose multiple subject, each subject can have multiple teacher.

```
Student A , B
Subject - C, D
Teacher - X, y, Z
```

Subject C can teach by Teacher X, Teacher Y

So Student A - take Subject C which is taught by Teacher X.

Now can I refer to the `TeacherSubject` table inside student?

```
public class Student
{
    public List<TeacherSubject> TeacherSubjects { get; set; }

    // rest 
}
```

Please anyone guide me.

Comment: yes, But A subject can teach by more than one teacher.

Comment: sorry my bad, please ignore my last comment. I was confused with names, apology. My answer is yes you can have

Comment: then, there is another column named as "StudentID" will added into `TeacherSubject` table? .Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you again need a many-to-many relationship between the student and subject-teacher mapping, because the same subject-teacher combination is applicable to many students.

so it would help if you had a separate table which should have studentid and subject-teacherid.

suppose you add the studentid column to student-teacher table. it will bring redundant data.